# Are $aX + bX$ and $bX + cX$ independent if $X$ is normal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

As in the title: $X$ is a Normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}_+$, $Y = aX + bX$ and $Z = bX + cX$. Are $Y$ and $Z$ independent?

Comment: I don't think this is related to discrete math btw.

Comment: Do you realize that $aX+bX=(a+b)X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not independent, in fact they are "on the opposite side of the spectrum",
i.e. they are fully linearly dependent.

Note that

$$Z = \frac{b+c}{a+b} \cdot Y$$

If you know the value of $Y$ you know the value of $Z$.
So there's no way these can be independent.

Also, I don't think it matters that $X$ is normal, it can be pretty much any random variable.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't look at it that way. Thanks.